# GEE model for repeated skewed outcome and group mean centered time varying covariates

Tags: skewness, mean, generalized-estimating-equations, time-varying-covariate

I have used GEE approach (log link with gamma distribution) to explore factors that are associated with outcomes of interest. My primary outcome of interest is highly skewed costs associated with an illness. In the dataset, there are time-invariant predictors such as gender, type of illness, ethnicity etc and time varying predictors: clinical scores. The main dependent outcome-costs and time-varying independent variable clinical score were measured at 4 equally spaced time-points. I am interested in modelling the dependence of the outcome variable on the covariates, and not in the pattern of change in the outcome variable over time. Further, my cohort is small (100 patients)

I introduced time as a categorical variable and no other covariates. The basic model with time alone indicated that there is not a significant time effect; in other words, the costs do not change over time. However, I still chose to keep time in the model as I felt it may be important clinically to account for variance between time-points. I have run subsequent models excluding time as well, and the results are similar.

During my initial analysis, I had used contemporaneous clinical scores (i.e. clinical scores at each time-point) to tease out whether clinical scores influences outcome: costs, but this was not significantly associated with the costs. However, when I aggregated these scores and included the average clinical score over a year, it was found that clinical scores were significantly associated with total costs

My final reduced GEE model is:

$$
\log(\mbox{costs})_{ij}= \beta_0 + \beta_1\mbox{ill} + \beta_2\mbox{sex}+ \beta_3\mbox{mcs}+ \beta_4t_{ij} + e_{ij}.
$$

$\mbox{ill}$ = type of illness
$\mbox{mcs}$ = mean clinical score
($i$ = ith individual & $j$ = occasion)

My doubts are:

1. I would like to know whether it is acceptable to include overall mean of a time-varying predictor variable (mean of clinical score) when I am not interested to know if change within individuals is significantly associated with outcome.I understand the interpretation of ß3 in the above equation will be change between individuals rather change within individuals.
2. Is it alright to build a GEE model with only time-invariant independent variables?
3. In case, If I am interested to tease out with-in individual influence of clinical scores on the outcome- is it possible to  include another variable indicating deviation from individual mean (mean clinical score)
   The new equation will then be:

   $$
   \log(\mbox{costs})_{ij}= \beta_0 + \beta_1\mbox{ill} + \beta_2\mbox{sex}+ \beta_3\mbox{mcs} + \beta_4(\mbox{cs}_{ij} - \mbox{mcs}) + \beta_5t_{ij} + e_{ij}.
   $$

   $\mbox{cs}$ = concurrent clinical scores (at 4 time-points)

Comment: I fixed the formulae, but let me suggest you simplify the question substantially as well as adding the appropriate i and j subscripts to the covariates where possible.

Comment: Thanks @AdamO; It looks much better, and I will bear that in mind